# How to stimulate EOF without preceding newline in C

Tags: c, eof

Lets say I have the below C code:

```
int getLine (char line[])
{
    int c, i=0;
    while( (c=getchar()) != EOF )
           line[i++]=c;
    line[i++] = c;
    return i;
}

>> Enter: 007
>> ^Z
>> Output:
```

If we closely observe the way I give output above, I am pressing `Enter` before stimulating EOF. This means, the length of string is 4 not 3 (excluding EOF).

When I am doing my exercises, I am really facing some trouble with that extra \n.

How do I stimulate EOF without newline? Is it possible at all?

```
>> Enter: 007^Z
>> ^Z
>> Output: length=6
```

Comment: On which platform?  On Unix and derivatives, you would type the EOF 'character' twice — usually control-D rather than control-Z, though.  That may also work on Windows; I don't know, but it is worth a try.  (On Unix, control-D makes the data on the line available to the program.  The first control-D gives it what you've typed already; the second gives it zero bytes to read, which is the indication of EOF.)

Comment: You should not save `EOF` in a `char` since `EOF` is negative and `char` could be `unsigned`.

Comment: on my shell Linux its working `~$ ./try 
07070707:~$ ` as commented by Mr. Jonathan Leffler

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think your comment should be an answer.

Comment: `EOF` is not a character, it's a condition. Imagine you ask your daughter for a banana and she says: "There are no bananas". The sentence "There are no bananas" is not a banana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

> On which platform? On Unix and derivatives, you would type the EOF 'character' twice — usually <kbd>control-D</kbd> rather than <kbd>control-Z</kbd>, though. That may also work on Windows; I don't know, but it is worth a try.

(A response comment affirms that the platform is Windows.)

> On Unix, <kbd>control-D</kbd> makes the data on the line available to the
>   program. The first <kbd>control-D</kbd> gives it what you've typed already; the
>   second gives it zero bytes to read, which is the indication of EOF.

Comment: Any references about it? I indeed find it that two `^d` can work like <kbd>Enter</kdb> in terminal and make me so puzzled.

Comment: I've not formally verified that they cover it, but I'd expect Stevens (et al) [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Environment-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0321637739/) or Rochkind [Advanced Unix Programming](http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-UNIX-Programming-Marc-Rochkind/dp/0131411543/) to cover it, and so might other Unix or Linux programming books, usually in the chapter on terminal handling.

Answer (score 1):

Then avoid storing the newline, in the loop. It's not as if you're being forced to store all characters regardless of value. :)

Also, you're not terminating the string correctly. This:

```
line[i++] = c;
```

should be:

```
line[i] = '\0';
```

And of course, it's sensitive to buffer overflow.

In general, you'd be better of using `fgets()`.

**EDIT**: I might be missing the point, but it seems to be that the entire focus on `EOF` is ... misguided, if all you want to do is read a line. Lines are not generally terminated with `EOF`, but with `\n`. So the function should probably just store characters until *either* `EOF` or `\n` is encountered.